# Switch between RDP connection on time schedule

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote

Is there a way to switch between RDP connection from one server to another one after a certain amount of time (like after 140 minutes) or maybe a way to schedule at what time it connects to server 1 and then log off and connects to server 2 and so on?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you run both session windows simultaneously? Then switch between the two?

Comment: no cause i am running a macro on a server which switchs server IP and from that point on the rdp needs to change to new server ip too